# Let be f a Isometry, show that the sequence doesn't converge

Tags: real-analysis

Given an isometry $f:M\to M$, fix a point $x_0\in M$ and define $x_1=f(x_0),...,x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$.

If $f(x_0)\neq x_0$, then the sequence $(x_n)$ doesn't converge.

My approach: I know the isometry is given by $d(x_n,x_{n-1})=d(f(x_n),f(x_{n-1}))$, where $x_n , x_{n-1}\in M$, but the isometry is like a bijection, then each point correspond only a point, but I don't see how continue. Regards

Comment: Don't you mean $x_{n+1}=f^{n-1}(x_n)$?

Comment: @Gary. No, in my book it is written so

Comment: Sorry, I meant that it follows that $x_{n+1}=f^{n-1}(x_0)$.

Comment: @Gary. But, a what refer with "fix point", it this meant $f(x_0)=x_0$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: show $d(x_n,x_{n-1})=d(x_{n-1},x_{n-2})$.

Comment: This is because, $d(x_n,x_{n-1})=d(f(x_{n-1}),f(x_{n-2}))=d(x_{n-1},x_{n-2})$

Comment: Yes, that is what being  an isometry means.

Answer (score 0):

Let's prove contrapositive, that is, if $(x_n)$ converges, then we have $f(x_0)=x_0$.

Suppose that $\lim x_n=a$. Given $\varepsilon>0$, exist $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n>n_0\Rightarrow d(x_n,a)<\dfrac\varepsilon2.$

Since $f$ is a isometry, then $f$ is continous. By the definition, $$f(a)=f(\lim x_n)=\lim f(x_n)=\lim x_{n+1}=a.$$

Observe that $$d(x_0,a)=d(f(x_0),f(a))=d(x_1,a)=d(f(x_1),f(a))=d(x_2,a)=\cdots=d(x_n,a).$$
From this follows $d(x_0,x_1)\leq d(x_0,a)+d(x_1,a)<\dfrac\varepsilon2+\dfrac\varepsilon2=\varepsilon$. Thus we have $$d(x_0,x_1)=d(x_0,f(x_0))=0\Rightarrow f(x_0)=x_0.$$